# producir un archivo cuyo contenido es la concatenación de las copias de los contenidos de f1 y f2

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo modificar el método de la pregunta 3 para convertirlo en un método que permita desde 2 archivos f1 y f2 para producir un tercer archivo cuyo contenido es la concatenación de las copias de los contenidos de f1 y f2 (en ese orden)?

Por el momento solo tengo el suficiente codigo para copiar un archivo a otro:

```
public class annale2013q3{

    public static void (File file,OutputStream os) throws {
        BufferInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        byte b ;
        do {
        b = bis.read( );
        if (b!= -1 ) os.write(b);
        }
        while (b!=-1);
        bis.close( );
    }   
}
```

Comment: Si usas Java 7 puedes usar `Files.copy` para copiar el primer archivo y modificar tu código para escribir a tu archivo en modo *append*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un método en la clase java.nio.file.Files que copia lo que hay en un archivo a un OutputStream.  Solo requieres cambiar método para que puedas enviar 2 archivos o más en un arreglo.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

```
    public static void (File[] entradas, File salida) throws IOException {

        java.io.FileOutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(salida);
        for (File entrada : entradas) {
            java.nio.file.Files.copy(entrada.toPath(), out);
            out.flush(); //este es importante antes de encadenar siguiente
        }
        out.close();  
    }
```